PhpMyAdmin: How can I modify the hierarchy to show Tables and Views collapsible items?
I'm not sure how to describe this problem. I'm in the process of migrating a database to a new laptop. I installed XAMPP 5.6.20 which includes PHP, MySQL, and PhpMyAdmin. So I exported the SQL statements and have created a new database with the same name as the original laptop and then have already executed all the statements on the new laptop. Now after I finished I noticed that the hierarchy is not the same. I can see that on the original laptop I can collapse tables and views in separate categories. Why is it not the same on the new laptop? On the new laptop all tables and views are in the same hierarchy without sub categories Tables and Views? I'm not sure if that is a big problem? Or is it just a configuration? Or did I create the database incorrectly? How to fix?


Take a backup with the too lol of Maria's  or mysql and restore with the tool of mariadb again

@nbk thank you for your response! "too lol" > sorry i didn't get this part. btw i noticed that my codebase still works regardless of whether there is this Tables/Views categories or not. So I guess this is not important and doesn't affect anything?

It is a typo because auto correction the tool is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html
